# Android: getResources() in try catch{}

Tags: android

This is part of my code:

```
/*Create overlay icon*/
mTextView01 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
List<Overlay> mList = mMapView01.getOverlays();
MapsOverlay mMapOverlay = new MapsOverlay(fromGeoPoint, mTextView01, this.getResources(),0);
mList.add(mMapOverlay);
```

When I want to add a processdialog, I write a new thread and in `try{}`, I use the above code.
However, there is error in `this.getResources()`.
Next, I delete, `this.`, there is no error...
But, when running the apps, it is not work.....(comparing to previous not open a new thread)

Is it the `getResources` problems?

Answer (score 4):

When you're inside the thread, "this" points to the Thread object and not to your activity; and the thread has no getResources() method, that's why you get the error.

So, you'll have to write `YourActivity.getResources()`.

I assume you're using the Thread to avoid blocking the main thread and then you update the UI based on the results you get. In this case using an AsyncTask instead of the Thread will make your code a lot cleaner. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Why was my answer modified with WRONG information added to it? `YourActivity.getResources()` won't work because `getResources()` is not static. 

The correct way is `YourActivity.this.getResources()` or just `getResources()`

Comment: sorry, either YourActivity.this.getResources() or getResources() is not ok....what can i do><??

Comment: you should look for the problem elsewhere, the way you call getResources() should not matter.

Comment: Most likely your problem is that you're calling something that needs to run on the UI thread from this other thread. To fix this you can use `runOnUiThread(Runnable action)` or a `Handler`.

Or, if you change the implementation and use AsyncTask instead of a Thread you can put the code that needs to be run on the UI thread in the `onPostExecute` method.

If it's only need to display a progress dialog , you show this dialog in `onPreExecute()` and dismiss it in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: but how about this:   this.getResources()

Comment: inside the Thread, `this` is pointing to the `Thread` instance and not to the `Activity` instance and the `Thread` does not have a `getResources()` method, that's why you get a compile error.

Comment: if I use AsyncTask, how can I include the resource instance?